# Websocket Java sending data to client more than 65536 bytes, size exceeds in browser

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket, socket.io

```
    //op - OutPutStream
    byte[] textBytes = strText.getBytes("UTF-8");
    op.write(0x81);
    if(textBytes.length < 127)
    {
        op.write(textBytes.length);
    }
    else
    if(textBytes.length >= 127 && textBytes.length <= 65536)
    {
        op.write(0x7E);
        op.write((textBytes.length >> 8) & 255);
        op.write((textBytes.length) & 255);
    }
    else
    if(textBytes.length > 65536)
    {
        op.write(0x7F);
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 56 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 48 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 40 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 32 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 24 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 16 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)((textBytes.length >> 8 ) & (byte)255));
        op.write((byte)(textBytes.length & (byte)255));
    }

    op.write(textBytes);
    op.flush();
```

the first if statement works if data is less than 127, and the second if block also is working, but the last block when the data is more than 65536 bytes, don't work, because in the browser I get an error that:

```
failed: WebSocket frame length too large: 295416440622254 bytes
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong in my last if statment? which bytes are incorrect?

Comment: What's your actual length that generates that failure?

Comment: @JonSkeet length of what, length of sending frame? this is the actual length 295416440622254

Comment: I'm asking for the value of `textBytes.length`. I doubt that you're genuinely trying to send 295,416,440,622,254 bytes.

Comment: @JonSkeet so I've logged my size of textBytes.length: 68563 - this is, and its more than 65536, so the last if statement is executed, but not worked, and 295,416,440,622,254 - is showing in the browser console

Comment: Right, so *next* you should log what bytes you're writing for the length, so you can compare them with what you actually want to write.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't find information on how bytes should be formed when the length is more than 65536, thats the problem...

Comment: Well the RFC looks like you're doing the right thing, and you should know what you *expect* your code to do. So log what it *actually* does and compare them.

Comment: Here is Java code that works: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketWriter.java#L334